# Filebeat config for reading a data from a specific path

Tags: docker-compose, elastic, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

i'm trying to setup elk stack using docker compose.
i'm using below file beat config

filebeat.inputs:

- type: filestream
  id: default-filestream
  paths:

  - ingest_data/*.log

filebeat.autodiscover:
providers:

- type: docker
  hints.enabled: true

processors:

- add_docker_metadata: ~

setup.kibana:
host: ${KIBANA_HOSTS}
username: ${ELASTIC_USER}
password: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}

output.elasticsearch:
hosts: ${ELASTIC_HOSTS}
username: ${ELASTIC_USER}
password: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
ssl.enabled: true
ssl.certificate_authorities: "certs/ca/ca.crt"

in the input config, i'm trying to pass log file from another path

- type: filestream
  id: default-filestream
  paths:

  - <my_log_file>
    But i'm not able to see the data in the kibana dashboard.
    Please let me know how to pass a user defined path for file beat config to get the datat

and if i launch a simple docker container, how to get the logs from the newly deployed container inside kibana ? do i need to use logstash ?

any help would be helpful.

thank you